# VPN network for DNS lookups?

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn

I want to provide a DNS server which filters out some websites. This should be used for mobile connections. I know that you cannot set a DNS server when connected through your smartphones mobile connection. This is where (I think) I need to create a VPN connection.

It's not my plan to route the whole traffic through my server since I only want to filter out some websites by DNS entries. Is there any way to tell the VPN connection to only route http traffic or even better only DNS queries?

Thanks

Comment: Which VPN are you using?

Comment: Not decided yet. A free and open source VPN solution for linux is preferred.